# Why we shouldn't dynamically allocate memory on stack in C?

Tags: c

We have functions to allocate memory on stack in both in windows and Linux systems but their use is discouraged also they are not a part of the C standard? This means that they provide some non-standard behavior. As I'm not that experienced I cannot understand what could be the problem when allocating memory from stack rather then using heap?

Thanks.

EDIT: My view: As Delan has explained that the amount of stack allocated to a program is decided during **compile** time so we cannot ask for more stack from the OS if we run out of it.The only way out would be a crash.So it's better to leave the stack for storage of primary things like variables,functions,function calls,arrays,structures etc. and use heap as much as the capacity of the OS/machine.

Comment: THERE IS NO C/C++ STANDARD! THERE IS NO C/C++ LANGUAGE! AAAARGH!

Comment: try to realize the truth: there is no spoon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack memory has the benefit of frequently being faster to allocate than heap memory.

However, the problem with this, at least in the specific case of [`alloca(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca), is that in many implementations, it just decreases the stack pointer, without giving regard or notification as to whether or not there actually is any stack space left.

The stack memory is fixed at compile- or runtime, and does not dynamically expand when more memory is needed. If you run out of stack space, and call `alloca`, you have a chance of getting a pointer to non-stack memory. You have no way of knowing if you have caused a stack overflow.

---

**Addendum:** this does not mean that we shouldn't use dynamically allocate stack memory; if you are

- in a heavily controlled and monitored environment, such as an embedded application, where the stack limits are known or able to be set
- keeping track of all memory allocations carefully to avoid a stack overflow
- ensuring that you don't recurse enough to cause a stack overflow

then stack allocations are fine, and can even be beneficial to save time (motion of stack pointer is all that happens) and memory (you're using the pre-allocated stack, and not eating into heap).

Comment: :Thanks,especially the second para is useful.Please read the EDIT part and tell whether I am right.Also is there a way to know at runtime how much stack mem. was allocated and how much of it is left.Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. If you feel that my answer is appropriate for your question, feel free to accept it.

Comment: In most situations, your understanding of the safe uses for the stack are right on. Of course, there are situations when allocating on the stack are good, given the right conditions, as outlined in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks.Also in my first comment I asked whether in a normal desktop app. can we know the stack size and how much of it is left at some moment.

Comment: For a normal desktop app, there are ways to find the stack size sometimes, but it's inconsistent and you should play it safe by avoiding array allocations on the stack. There definitely isn't a way, in any case, to find out how much is left -- you must keep track of that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Memory on stack (automatic in broader sense) is **fast**, **safe** and **foolproof** compared to heap.

**Fast**: Because it's allocated at compile time, so no overhead involved

**safe**: It's exception safe. The stack gets automatically wound up, when exception is thrown.

**full proof**: You don't have to worry about `virtual` destructors kind of scenarios. The destructors are called in proper order.

Still there are sometimes, you have to allocate memory runtime, at that time you can first resort on standard containers like `vector`, `map`, `list` etc. Allocating memory to row pointers should be always a judicious decision.

Comment: Uh, I believe that this is not true. You can easily cause a stack overflow without knowing, as there is no mechanism in place to discern whether a stack-allocated pointer is actually still in the stack.

Comment: @Delan, I never said stackoverflow cannot happen.

Comment: Well, it's not really safe then, is it?

Comment: @Delan, please read my answer. I have evaluated the meanings of each term.

Comment: I think you're over-generalising its safety with one reason, while ignoring one glaring other reason that makes it unsafe (without proper care; I'm not saying that all stack allocations are bad).